# C# How can I be able to allow user to timein and time out morning and afternoon

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this query that checks for the user existence,

```
string query1 = ("Select * from payroll.attendance WHERE Date='" + 
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' AND Username='" + lbluser.Text + "' ");
```

If the user has already timein the query will check and wont allow you to time to the current date.
I need to disallow him to timein if he already timein in the morning, and then once its already afternoon 12pm to 4 the user will be allowed to time in again.

Additional information I need to do is allow and require the user to timein and timeout every morning, start time is 8am and end time is 12, and then in afternoon require the user to time in again with the starttime of 1pm then upto 4pm,

Comment: I've tried putting another WHERE Clause TIMEIN<=12:00, It doesnt work though, and seems like if it would work I'd probably have few more problems since I'm not using 24 hour time format.

Comment: @yang: `"not using 24 hour time format"` - How are you not?  Date/time data types take care of that automatically.  For starters, you should *at least* be using query parameters instead of this SQL-injectable string concatenation.  Then you can also just pass `DateTime.Now` *itself* rather than building a custom string.

Comment: though I am using this ("HH:mm"); for my datetime, it still shows me 12 hour format, anyway datetime is not a big deal here.

Comment: Your date comparison may not work if your `Date` column is type of `DateTime`. It must be either `Date` type or use `date` function with your `Date` column as `date(Date)='your date value'`.